# How to vacuum an sqlite database within R?

Tags: r, sqlite, dbi, vacuum

I have created and filled a sqlite database within R using packages DBI and RSQLite. E.g. like that:

```
con_sqlite <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "../mydatabase.sqlite")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con_sqlite, "mytable", d_table, overwrite = TRUE)
...
```

Now the sqlite file got too big and I reduced the tables. However, the size does not decrease and I found out that I have to use command vaccum. Is there a possibility to use this command within R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
DBI::dbExecute(con, "VACUUM;")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Was not aware of the execute possibility :)

Comment: You can send any arbitrary sql command that way, which is nice to have if the dbplyr functions are missing some functionality.

Comment: `dbExecute` is paired nicely with `dbGetQuery`: they both nicely clean up after themselves, where the first does not expect a return value and the latter does. They both effectively call their equivalent slightly-lower-level functions `dbSendStatement` and `dbSendQuery`, where `dbFetch` it required to retrieve the results, and both `dbSend*` require `dbClearResult` afterward.